# Extracting points from LineString or Polygon and making dictionary out of them in GeoPandas

Tags: python, coordinates, geopandas, linestring, geodataframe

I am building some pre-processing routines for 3D visualization of GIS data and I have several line and polygon shapefiles with multiple features. I want to extract the points for each of the features along with the feature attributes and create a dictionary of point GeoDataFrames.

This I suspect is easy to do, but I am not quite sure how to index into the LineString within a GeoDataFrames.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I had the same question, here we can use a lambda function:

```py
import geopandas as gpd

gdf = gpd.read_file('some_lines.shp')
```

Say your GeoDataFrame looks like this:

```
   id xs_ID Orientatio                                           geometry
0   0     W      SW-NE  LINESTRING (4017476.264886954 19792128.2156728)
1   1     E        N-S  LINESTRING (4030453.382825969 19837548.1284593)
```

Simply write a function to extract the points from the LineStrings:

```py
def linestring_to_points(feature,line):
    return {feature:line.coords}

gdf['points'] = gdf.apply(lambda l: linestring_to_points(l['xs_ID'], l['geometry']), axis=1)
```

now if you print `gdf['points']`:

```
0    {'W': ((4017476.2648869543, 19792128.215672825...
1    {'E': ((4030453.382825969, 19837548.128459394)...
```

The same routine should work with polygons too! (amusing `gdf` now has polygons instead of lines):

```py
def poly_to_points(feature,poly):
    return {feature:poly.exterior.coords}

gdf['points'] = gdf.apply(lambda p: linestring_to_points(p['xs_ID], p['geometry']), axis=1)
```

Comment: thank you very much for posting this answer I will check it and get back to you. I think I posted this on the geopandas forum and received an answer I didn't fully understand so I am excited to see a lambda function being used because it is a much easier solution to understand.

Answer (score 4):

Creating points using the apply function doesn't require a dict as they remain indexed in the output DataFrame. We can use list comprehension with an apply function to solve in one line:

```py
gdf['points'] = gdf.apply(lambda x: [y for y in x['geometry'].coords], axis=1)
```

and then call:

```py
gdf.to_dict('records')
```