# "AttributeError: 'GeoSeries' object has no attribute 'coords'" when accessing coords property of LineString using GeoPandas

Tags: geometry, coordinates, geopandas, shapely, linestring

How can I access the `.coords` property of a LineString in GeoDataFrames?

I can access other properties, such as area, length, etc, as documented in the [Shapely's documentation](http://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#linestrings). See reproducible example below:

```py
# create example GeoDataFrame with LineString`
line_new = LineString([(0.3, 0.6), (1.5, 1.6), (0.9,2.5)])
df = gpd.GeoDataFrame()
df.loc[0, 'geometry'] = line_new
```

This works:`df.geometry.length`

```
0    2.643715
dtype: float64
```

But this does not: `df.geometry.coords`. It returns the following error:

> ```
>     return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
>
> AttributeError: 'GeoSeries' object has no attribute 'coords'
> ```

My understanding from the [GeoPandas Documentation](http://geopandas.org/data_structures.html) was that the `'geometry'` GeoSeries in a GeoDataFrame was a Shapely object, and thus the respective properties/methods would be available:

> The GeoSeries class implements nearly all of the attributes and methods of Shapely objects.

Is the `coords` attribute simply one of the few that are not implemented?

Is this the same as what is being asked in [How do I extract points from a LineString or Polygon data frame and make a dictionary of point data frames?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/238533/how-do-i-extract-points-from-a-linestring-or-polygon-data-frame-and-make-a-dicti)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A GeoSerie is a list of shapely geometries, therefore

1. with shapely

   ```py
   from shapely.geometry import LineString, shape

   line_new = LineString([(0.3, 0.6), (1.5, 1.6), (0.9,2.5)])
   type(shape(line_new))
   <class 'shapely.geometry.linestring.LineString'>
   list(shape(line_new).coords)
   [(0.3, 0.6), (1.5, 1.6), (0.9, 2.5)]
   ```
2. with your GeoDataFrame (list of shapely geometries)

   ```py
   type(df.geometry)
   <class 'geopandas.geoseries.GeoSeries'>
   df['geometry'].coords
   ....
   AttributeError: 'GeoSeries' object has no attribute 'coords'
   ```

First row of the GeoSerie = first shapely geometry

```py
type(df.geometry.iloc[0])
<class 'shapely.geometry.linestring.LineString'>
list(df.geometry.iloc[0].coords)
[(0.3, 0.6), (1.5, 1.6), (0.9, 2.5)]
```

Comment: Thank you. I still don't understand why `df['geometry'].length` works however - do you have any insight?

Comment: Because the result of list(LineSring.coords) is a list (number of items > 1) and not a single value as in `df.geometry.length` or a dictionary as in [How do I extract points from a LineString or Polygon data frame and make a dictionary of point data frames?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/238533/how-do-i-extract-points-from-a-linestring-or-polygon-data-frame-and-make-a-dicti)

Answer (score 0):

If the answer by @gene doesn't work, check here: [How to convert GeoSeries polygons to lists of coordinates?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/300747/how-to-convert-geoseries-polygons-to-lists-of-coordinates)

Where they suggest df.geometry.exterior.coords.xy which will spit out arrays with the boundary coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

Things have changed since this question was asked. Use `geopandas.GeoSeries.get_coordinates()` to get coordinates.

Documentation link [here](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoSeries.get_coordinates.html).