# How to convert GeoSeries polygons to lists of coordinates?

Tags: geopandas, geodataframe, geoseries

I have a GeoDataFrame consisting polygons. How can I convert each polygon into a list of coordinates? Is there any attribute, method or function in GeoPandas to do this?

[image]

Answer (score 6):

A very effective, very fast solution would be to build a function and then use apply instead of a list comprehension

```
def coord_lister(geom):
    coords = list(geom.exterior.coords)
    return (coords)

coordinates = shp.geometry.apply(coord_lister)
```

Comment: What is `geometry` here? A complete example would be more helpful.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the following list comprehension to achieve this:

`[list(shp.geometry.exterior[row_id].coords) for row_id in range(shp.shape[0])]`

where `shp` is your geopandas dataframe. It uses the `exterior` and `coords` methods from shapely.

Comment: It worked, though there is a problem with multipolygons. Thanks!

Comment: `[list(shp.geometry.exterior.iloc[row_id].coords) for row_id in range(shp.shape[0])]`

Answer (score 0):

`shp.geomtery.get_coordinates()` worked for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).